# Escaping forward slash in PostgreSQL JSON

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a JSON object with a timestamp:

```
{"Date/Time": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"}
```

I'm trying to query this directly and convert it to a date type (with YYYY-MM) like so:

```
SELECT
    to_char(DATE (data->>'Date/Time'), 'YYYY-MM') as datetime
FROM
    mytable;
```

assuming the column `data` holds the JSON object, I get the error:
`invalid input syntax for type date: "time"`

Is this because of the key having a forward slash? If so, how do I escape it? (escaping the forward slash with a back slash like `data->>'Date\/Time'` doesn't search for the right key anymore)

Comment: Made some edits to the original JSON, Date/Time is supposed to be the key storing the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that `"YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS"` in your question is actually a real timestamp value like `2018-07-13 18:55:42` and not the characters you have shown.

---

`to_char()` expects a `date` or `timestamp` value and converts that to a string. You want to the other way: convert a string to a timestamp. For that you need to use `to_timestamp()`

```
to_timestamp('{"Date/Time": "2018-07-13 18:55:42"}'::json ->> 'Date/Time', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

returns the value as an actual `timestamp` value. If you want a `DATE` rather than a `timestamp` you can use `to_date()` instead of `to_timestamp()`

If you want to format that so that only year and month are displayed, you can format that timestamp using `to_char()`

```
to_char(to_timestamp('{"Date/Time": "2018-07-13 18:55:42"}'::json ->> 'Date/Time', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
       'yyyy-mm') as datetime
```

Comment: Looks good. Just wondering, if I had some records where Date/Time doesn't map to anything (i.e., "") then would this break?

Comment: @itsmewiththeface: you could wrap `data->>'Date/Time'` into `isnull(data->>'Date/Time', '')`